# Using GET, POST and GLOBALS

Tags: php, post, get

I'm trying to sort table of data by it's columns(as hyperlinks), but also to navigate using < or > buttons.

```
<?php
...

if (isset($_POST["next"]) && isset($_POST["start"]))
{
    //force start to be an integer and add 5 to it
    $start = (int)$_POST["start"] + 5;
}
elseif (isset($_POST["prev"]) && isset($_POST["start"]))
{
    //force start to be an integer and remove 5 from it
    $start = (int)$_POST["start"] - 5;
}
else
{
    $start = 0;
}

// if one of hyperlinks in table heading was clicked
if (isset($_GET["sort"]))
{
    $orderByFields = ["TerritoryDescription", "RegionDescription"];
    $GLOBALS['sort'] = $_GET["sort"];
    ...
    SQL here.
}
else
{
...
}


//problem here
// if next button was pressed
if (isset($_POST['next']))
{
    echo 'next';
    if (isset($_GET['sort']))
    {
    echo 'sort';
    //undefined
    //i'm trying to retrive value here.
    echo $GLOBALS['sort'];
    }
}

// if prev button was pressed
elseif (isset($_POST['prev']))
{
    echo 'prev';
}
...

?>
```

I'm trying to retrieve value $GLOBALS['sort'] when < or > button was pressed so I can sort the SQL results by $GLOBALS['sort']. But the variable is undefined when I try to access from outside.

Comment: I'm suspecting you're expecting the value to stick until the following request(s). In this case you'll need to either store it (here, `sort`) into the session, or manually pass it along to the following requests.

Comment: thx jeto i used SESSION variable for sort and it worked!